# How can I add a 2-column legend to a Matlab plot?

Tags: matlab, plot, graph, legend, legend-properties

Consider following code:

```
t=0:.01:(2*pi);
y=[sin(t);sin(t-pi/12);sin(t-pi/6);sin(t-pi/4)];
figure(1)
    clf
    subplot(6,1,5)
    plot(t,y)
    xlim([0 2*pi])
    legend('1','2','3','4')
```

It produces following figure:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Is there a way to change the legend to a 2-column lay-out? So it would be

> --- 1 --- 3
>
> --- 2 --- 4

instead of

> --- 1
>
> --- 2
>
> --- 3
>
> --- 4

so the legend boundary lined would not cross the graph boundary lines.

I found the [`gridLegend`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29248-gridlegend-a-multi-column-format-for-legends) script, but I prefer to code it directly.

Comment: Not sure if you can with orthodox methods but really interesting question. Probably someone can hack into java and do it. Probably `gridLegend` is best

Comment: If you want to code it directly then follow along with what `gridLegend` is doing and implement it yourself.

Comment: @excaza Yes, that was also my first idea. But it seems that it is not as easy as adding 1 or 2 lines of code to a `legend` statement.

Comment: I would advise to simply use `gridLegend`. There's really no point re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: What about `legend('1','2','3','4','Orientation','horizontal')` so the legend doesn't cross the border of the axes? This might not solve your *question* but could be a straight-forward solution to your *problem*.

Comment: @Matt Indeed, that's an interesting alternative I hadn't thought of.

Comment: Other than gridlegend there's also columnlegend: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27389-columnlegend

Comment: @Karlo, I have given a direct solution to your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MATLAB has introduced native support for multiple columns in legend from **version 2018a**. Just add `'NumColumns',desired_number` at the end of the `legend()` command.

See details here - https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/legend.html?lang=en&s_tid=gn_loc_drop#bt6r30y

Additionally, the orientation of the legend entries can be changed from top-to-bottom to left-to-right.

> By default, the legend orders the items from top to bottom along each
>   column. To order the items from left to right along each row instead,
>   set the Orientation property to 'horizontal'.

Answer (score 1):

You can usually hack this sort of thing by making a second invisible axis on top of the first, like this:

```
t=0:.01:(2*pi);
y=[sin(t);sin(t-pi/12);sin(t-pi/6);sin(t-pi/4)];
figure
subplot(6,1,5)

plot(t,y)
xlim([0 2*pi])
l1 = legend('1', '2');
pos = l1.Position;
set(l1, 'Position', pos - [pos(3) 0 0 0]);
legend boxoff

ax2 = copyobj(gca, gcf);
set(ax2, 'visible', 'off', 'clipping', 'off')
kids = ax2.Children;
set(kids, 'visible', 'off', 'clipping', 'off')
set(ax2, 'children', kids([3:4 1:2]))
l2 = legend(ax2, '3', '4');
legend(ax2, 'boxoff')
legend boxoff
```

Note that this is fragile (e.g., doesn't handle the window being resized on my version of MATLAB).

Comment: Interesting hack. Could indeed be improved so the two legends are at the same height for each figure window size.